# Can't install OpenKinect for Processing Library

Tags: processing, openkinect

I'm trying to use the OpenKinect for Processing Library on Processing 3 (Windows 11).
The last update to the library was in 2015 but the original author has some great video tutorials online that I'd like to learn from. I'm stuck trying to get Processing to recognize the library.  What I've done so far is download the .zip from github, unzip, place the files in the 'libraries' folder in Processing.

But when I go to examples in Processing, the library's examples don't show up.  When I drag an example into the window, I get "No library found for org.openkinect.processing". The unzipped file has a few additional folders in their so I also attempted to place the main library folder in Processing/libraries as well.  What am I doing wrong[image]?

Comment: Unzipping https://github.com/shiffman/OpenKinect-for-Processing/releases/download/1.0/openkinect_processing.zip then moving the `openkinect_processing` folder to Documents/Processing/libraries should do the trick. (It's unclear how you for the OpenKinect-for-Processing-1.0 and OpenKinect-Processing folders. As a general rule the name of the library will match the name of the jar file inside the `library` folder: e.g. Documents/processing/libraries/openkinect_processing/library/openkinect_processing.jar). Which version of the Kinect are you using and what functionality do you need mainly ?